# Test Flash in Full Screen Mode

Tags: flash, debugging, text, adobe, fullscreen

I am creating a flash, virtually it has 2 columns, right side play a video, and the left side will display some text. But there is a problem. The flash and text both are fine when I play flash in window mode, however, when I press Ctrl+F enters into full screen mode, the text won't show up. If I exit the full screen, the text show up again. Go back to full screen disappear again. So weird.

So I try to debug the flash by dumping some trace result to the Output panel. Since the problem only happened in full screen mode, so I really need to test the flash in full screen mode. But I cannot find a way to test the flash (Ctrl+Enter) in full scree mode.

Someone know can help me? Why the text disappear OR Why to test flash in full screen mode? Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am using Action Script 2.

Comment: you cannot test in fullscreen mode in the IDE, only in the browser, and you should have allowFullscreen set to true in HTML. Also, have a look at the fullscreenRect property of the stage(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#fullScreenSourceRect), you can use it to configure the visible area when in fullscreen mode. You are talking about fullscreen mode in the browser, right ?

Comment: I am running the .ext file, there is a Full Screen Option, but like you said in IDE there is no Full Screen Option. I used allowFullscreen setting, so after I double click .exe file, it enters into full screen automatically. I haven't embedded to the browser yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use firebug or write a function that writes your traces to the HTML page, via an external JS function...

```
    public static function screenTrace(traceMessage:String)
    {
        ExternalInterface.call('screenTrace', traceMessage);
    }



function initializeScreenTrace() {
tracesWindow = window.open('','traces','width=400, height=300')
tracesWindow.document.writeln(
'<html><head><title>Console</title></head>'
    +'<body bgcolor=white onLoad="self.focus()">'
  +'</body></html>'
)
```

}

```
 function screenTrace(targetString) {
if (tracesWindow != undefined)
{
tracesWindow = window.open('','traces','width=400, height=300')
tracesWindow.document.writeln(
'<html><head><title>Console</title></head>'
+'<body bgcolor=white onLoad="self.focus()">'
  +'</body></html>'
    )
  tracesWindow.document.writeln("<br>" + targetString);
}

 }
```

This should let you get some traces to figure out the problem.

SCREENTRACE
START TRACING.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but if you have forgotten to embed your text that would explain the problem. If you forget to embed text it looks ok on your machine at one size because  you have the font, but if you scale or rotate the textfield it will simply disappear. This is just a guess though. There might be something else going on. Assuming your using CS5 here is how to [embed fonts](http://www.dotstrosity.net/2010/05/10/flash-cs5-font-embedding-its-totally-different/).

As far as I know, there is no way to test fullscreen in the ide.

Comment: Well, the text is in a p tag, and with fonts (Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;) I guess there is no problem for the font embedding. Thanks you. By the way, how do you usually debug flash?

Comment: did you try embedding just verdana? I bet that will solve your problem. For debugging small stuff I use the ide. For large projects I use http://demonsterdebugger.com/ with flex or flash.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't solve the problem. This is how I embedded the font. mc_layout_2.mc_layout_2_fadeIn.layout_2_Text.htmlText = "<p>"+COMP_pageText[ChangeTo-1]+"</p>"; then the css for p tag is p {  
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  font-size: 15px;  
  color:#000000;
} Thank you for your recommendation of demonsterdebugger will try that later.